# What if the geographic pole were in the Himalayas?

Tags: science-based, climate, alternate-earth

From a climatic point of view, what if Earth went through a radical polar shift that would place the geographical pole right where the Himalayas and Tibetan Plateau are? (No matter if southern or northern pole.. let's say southern).

These are some of the driest regions in the world, so I wonder if there would be enough humidity to form an ice sheet. Would that result in a polar cap with a dry area in the middle?

Note that if I’m right the opposite pole would lie somewhere offshore of Chile.

Here's a handy map i did :)

[image: :O]

Comment: Actually Antarctica is drier than Tibet... Antarctica gets an average of 166 mm of water per year, while Tibet gets around 250 mm of water per year (from 110 to 500, depending on the specific location). And yet the Antarctic is covered by 3 to 4 kilometers of ice.

Comment: Yes but I guess Antarctica is dry precisely because it's on the southern pole and all of its water is trapped as ice, not because of topography. What I mean is that if Antarctica was on the same latitude of Tibet it wouldn't be as dry. I guess my question could be rephrased as: what if the pole was placed on a +4500 m high plateau?

Comment: Are you suggesting that Earth will keep the axial tilt at about 23 degrees, or it will start spinning on its side, like Uranus?

Comment: @JRover: And if Tibet were on the equator it woudn't be as dry. But it isn't, and moreover it's in the middle of an enormous continent. The important bit is that although precipitation in the Antarctic is very low, similar to Sahara, *evaporation is even lower* because it's very cold. Over millions of years this means enormously thick ice sheets.

Comment: @AlexP I can see what you mean. My understanding is that the Himalayan plateau isn't actually dry because of latitude but because of its elevation (eg, if it was placed somewhere else on the planet it would still be very dry) somewhat similar to the Atacama Desert, which could be 200 million years old and has moved a lot since. But you're right. ice will accumulate eventually... I'm just not sure if it would accumulate at the same rate on a very high plateau, but i guess it would only take more time.

Comment: @Alexander same tilt, same speed, same everything, but the crust has shifted such that another portion of it covers the geographic pole :) This is an actual super interesting phenomenon that has happened many times in Earth's geological history, look it up https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/True_polar_wander

Comment: Excellent map! I deleted the dreaded second question "What about the other changes in Earth’s global climate?" That is way way too broad. The question about the poles is just right. Feel free to ask followup questions using the same map if there are other areas of interest you want to know more about.

Comment: Here's a relevant [xkcd](https://what-if.xkcd.com/10/) comic about rotating Earth's continents. Basically, you're going to upend the climate everywhere; predicting exact effects is beyond our current knowledge, but it's not going to be the Earth we know.

Comment: @JRover - Well, according to that link, it's been a very slow and minor process - as you would expect, the torque required to significantly change the Earth's axis of rotation, or shift the lithosphere relative to the rest of the planet, on a human timescale would have side effects including the complete destruction of the surface, probable loss of the oceans and elimination of all life.

Comment: @JRover: Antarctica actually does have some fairly high mountains, which would likely be higher still if it weren't for the weight of accumulated ice pressing the continent down.  So as a semi-educated guess, any change wouldn't be due to the nature of the Tibetan Plateau itself, but because it's surrounded by land rather than ocean.   There would be a greater extent of ice because the glaciers wouldn't break off in the ocean - probably to a latitude equivalent to Tierra del Fuego.

Comment: I think this link could help with the climate: https://what-if.xkcd.com/10/ Since it's not too different from the polar position to you had showed us.

Comment: Antarctica is the highest continent on earth, on average. There are plateaus above 4500m (the pole is about half of that) where there are still massive ice sheets. The elevation presumably wouldn't impact the fact that there will be ice there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since it's not too different from the polar position to you had showed us.

Quoting from the article of "XKCD whatif" in question:
"The climate on the rotated Earth would depend heavily on the details of ocean and atmospheric heat circulation. We'll guess at some of that, but for now, let's assume this world has extremes which are similar to ours."

[image: Horse Latitudes]

This map shows the air movement with horse latitudes with the equator provides moisture from the oceans, which then gathers into rain. Then the water from the rain maintains the tropical fertility of the area. Areas near the equator get seasonal monsoon cycles. Which would be similar to the map provided:

[image: Hurricane Basins]

the red areas show where hurricanes might occur.

In temperate zones, they have more variety in weather. They are dominated by the movement of the jet streams, fronts, and on the geography. Climates can be hard to exactly predict completely but you'll get the picture when you test it out yourself.
But at least this likely the closest map I could get to the Himalayas being the north pole/south pole.

I take no credit for any of this information, I just thought I'd share it since it can help explain some things.

Comment: Welcome to WorldBuilding Stack Exchange! We have a policy about links in answers. The relevant info from the link should be spelled out in the answer itself, with the link as a source/extended reading. Could you add quotations from the link or summarize the 'take-away' of the link, such that people can still read your answer if the link were to go down?

Comment: Welcome Idola, check out the [help] and [tour] to get familiar with the site.  Your answer is more commentary than an actual answer to the question.  SE is a little different than discussion forums.  Its all about specific questions with specific answers.  As is stands this is more commentary than an answer to the question and may get deleted/converted into a comment.  Answers should work within the framework of the question, answer the question, and provide support for the answer given.

Comment: The XKCD link does indeed seem perfect, however you've now completely copied the XKCD whatif here which unless you have a license for it breaches the copyright. You can summarize the article without being a link only article or breaching copyright - but if you copy the entire thing that isn't good :(

Answer (score 5):

## Dry-ness won't stay the same due to differing wind cycles

[image]

The Earth, due to its rotation, generally has three 'cells' of circulating air. The Hadley cell, Mid-latitude cell, and Polar cell. Due to the patterns of rising and falling air, these cells cause the same general climate patterns to emerge around the Earth (assisted in large part by oceanic currents). I'll describe some of the general effects briefly.

The Hadley cell generally causes wet conditions at the equator and dry conditions at 30 degrees. You can see this on each continent with the tropical rainforests near the equator and the worldwide bands of desert around 30 N and S.

The Mid-latitude cell generally features Mediterranean climates (wet winters, dry summers) on West coasts of continents at lower latitudes, but cool wet climates on West coasts at higher latitudes. Examples are [Spain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seville#Climate) vs. [England](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bristol#Climate); Los Angeles vs. [Seattle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seattle#Climate); [Santiago](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Santiago#Climate) vs. [Valdivia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valdivia#Climate) in Chile. The East coasts of continents in the Mid-latitude cell are generally much hotter and wetter in the summer. Compare the summer conditions of [San Francisco](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/San_Francisco#Climate) and [Washington DC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Washington,_D.C.#Climate), or [Lisbon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lisbon#Climate) and [Seoul](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seoul#Climate).

The Polar cell is generally devoid of moisture. Rainfall north of 60 degrees is generally very low; for example look at [Yakutsk, Russia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yakutsk#Climate) or [Barrow, Alaska](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barrow,_Alaska#Climate).

## Conclusion

The polar ice caps are dry! In fact, Barrow is significantly drier than Tibet. Yet it still snows there every month of the year, and sees almost a meter of snow a year. Antarctica is drier still, and has miles of ice in places.

All in all, your poles are going to be dry, but as long as they are cold enough, they are going to develop ice caps over time.

Answer (score 3):

Such a shift would dramatically change Earth's climate and ocean currents...
so it's very difficult to predict if -and how fast- a new ice cap would appear.

One thing you should really think about is ocean currents.
Antarctica is extremely cold because it's surrounded by cold water. The antarctic circumpolar current is a permanent cold stream around Antarctica's landmass, and it prevents hot water from reaching the land, and warming it.

In your example, such a circumpolar current should not appear. A warm current may even come from the Indian Ocean and have an impact on your new polar region. See how the Gulf Stream is warming Scandinavia...

So, there should be ice in the mountains, but it's hard to say how far it would expand, and if it will cover Taklamakan desert. It depends on the new climate this polar shift will create on Earth... A new ice age ? A new warm age ? It's up to you.